# Displaying form content instead of form object name

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a form in a template. I think I have accomplished this however I a missing a piece. This is what I currently see:

[image]

I think I am missing something from my form class that should display the choices.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    one = forms.ChoiceField(choices=('HDFS', 'HDFS'), widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    two = forms.ChoiceField(choices=('HIVE', 'HIVE'), widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    three = forms.ChoiceField(choices=('BOTH', 'Both of HDFS and HIVE'), widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    beatle = [one, two, three]
    event_textarea = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '8', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Events...', 'id': 'event_textarea'})
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request == 'POST':
        # create a form instane and populate it with data from the request
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            form.cleaned_data()
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/test/')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'home/home_page.html', {'form': form})
```

template:

```
{% extends 'index/index.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% block head %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}home/js/home.js" async></script>
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}home/css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock head %}

{% block content %}

  <div>Welcome to Trinity E2E testing</div>

  <form id="test-form" action="/test/" method="post"> {# pass data to /test/ URL #}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for radio in form.beatle %}
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
      {{ radio }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form.event_textarea }}

    <input id="submit-test" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Submit">
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beatle` list contains references to class attributes, not instance attributes.

How about make it a instance method to return instance attributes (form fields):

```
def beatle(self):
    return [self.one, self.two, self.three]
```

**UPDATE**

To correctly return bound fields:

```
def beatle(self):
    return [self['one'], self['two'], self['three']]
```

or

```
def beatle(self):
    return [self[name] for name in ['one', 'two', 'three']]
```

Comment: I tried this out but I am having a bit of a problem knowing which places to change the code. This is the error I am getting http://postimg.org/image/p57xncwez/ and the changes I made: http://dpaste.com/2FZ2BFC

Comment: @Liondancer, You did it right. Could you show the full traceback?

Comment: I am still getting the same error: http://dpaste.com/164XGPA image: http://postimg.org/image/dv7rvhwfn/ =[
 I just need the buttons to display HDFS, HIVE, BOTH of HDFS and HIVE respectively and have an textarea be displayed

Comment: This fixed the problem! sort of.. haha I am trying to create custom Radio buttons and I'm following the example in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect  but the "radio button" properties arent begin generated. http://postimg.org/image/nr94y29bh/

Comment: I think the code created 3 separate radio button sections that's why all 3 can be selected

Comment: @Liondancer, If you want three radio buttons in a group, you need to use **a single ChoiceField** with those choices (not three `ChoiceField`)